# How to change FontSize of WPF DatePicker watermark (and the textbox showing the date)?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I only targets the style change of watermark/textbox; It seems that FontSize attribute doesn't apply to the watermark/textbox/dropdown-calendar of WPF DatePicker, while FontStyle or FontWeight works perfectly.

(For FontFamily, it only applies to the dropdown-calendar but not the watermark/textbox.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Watermark textbox of date picker is a part of date picker textbox. You just apply your style to date picker textbox and override default wpf style and template of datepicker.

[DatePicker Syles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468215(v=vs.110).aspx)

[DatePickerTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datepickertextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

good luck!!